# Floating pictures on an HTML page with CSS

Tags: html, css, image, button, banner

For my class, I need to have 3 pictures of the same size float beside my buttons, but under my banner.

I have 6 buttons going up-and-down on the far left with a banner above everything else on the very top.

I want the three images to be with one on the far right, one in between them on the far left beside the buttons, and one on the far right under the first. I would post a picture, but have no reputation.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome. You may add a link to your image, someone will quickly replace the link with the image. See [ask] to get some guidance for posting, in particular, show the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Improved readability of the question a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this work for you? I left some comments to explain some things. This is what I pictured you were wanting. I used images, but this can be anything (divs, h, p, etc). http://jsfiddle.net/670fvtb8/

```
<header><h1>header goes here</h1></header>

<div class="col-left">
    <ul>
        <li>button</li>
        <li>button</li>
        <li>button</li>
        <li>button</li>
        <li>button</li>
        <li>button</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-right">
    <img src="/your-image-path.jpg" class="first">
    <img src="/your-image-path.jpg" class="mid">
    <img src="/your-image-path.jpg" class="last">
</div>
```